# Why is my NSmutableDictionary being turned into a NSCFString?

Tags: nsdictionary

I have a dictionary allocated and ready to go in the appDelegate of my program.

```
//appdel.m
    NSMutableDictionary *dict;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: (NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Overide point for customization after application launch.

    dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];


    dict = HBLoadDictionary(@"/dict.plist");

    // Add the tab bar controller's view to the window and display.
    [self.window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

so I wanted this dictionary to exist in other files so I made it an external in other files to be edited and read from.

```
 //viewcontroller.m
    extern NSMutableDictionary *dict;
```

and later on I decide to set an object for a key. event is just an EKevent.

```
NSString* str = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", event.eventIdentifier];
NSString *eID  = [[NSString alloc]init];
eID = [data valueForKey:@"id"];
[dict setObject:str forKey:eID];
```

when I make a call to the function I'll get this

-[NSCFString setObject:forKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

At one point I even got a UIImage instead of a NSCFString which lead me to believe that memory is an issue and i'm not handling it right. Why is it even changing types like that? cause its causing function calls to mess up...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `NSMutableDictionary` you allocated is immediately replaced by the return value from `HBLoadDictionary`.  I would assume that `HBLoadDictionary` returns an autoreleased object, which you're not retaining anywhere.  Shortly after you load the dictionary, it's deallocated so `dict` points to freed memory.  Also, the first NSMutableDictionary that you allocated is leaked.

You can fix it by replacing

```
dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
dict = HBLoadDictionary(@"/dict.plist");
```

with

```
dict = [HBLoadDictionary(@"/dict.plist") retain];
```

As a side note, it's bad practice to initialize a global variable in an objective-c method.  Although you probably won't have more than one application delegate, and its application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method won't be called more than once, this could cause a memory leak in other situations.  You're better off just having a class method that returns a static variable.

Comment: Your right I didn't think it would be possible to wrap a c method in a retain. As far as leaks go I have quite a view but i'm patching them up. I didn't think about having a static variable though, that would be my singleton right?

Comment: Right, the static variable would be your singleton.  You'd access it using something like [MyAppDelegate dict], which is a class method that should always return the same object.  You would have a static NSMutableDictionary variable in the implementation that is initialized to nil.  After the declaration, check if the variable is nil, and if it is, initialize it using the line in the answer above.